# from Python run PS command with argument (quotation and slashes)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, powershell, command-line

I'd like to change my current password from Python script using PowerShell. For this I need to run PowerShell command from the code bellow. What would be the best way to do that?

```
import datetime
#generated password is always changing. There might be different quotations and slashes so it's tricky to put it into PowerShell command bellow
generated_password=r'/#\n\9{S;-l2H~'

#password to set is changing depending on date. Let's say today it has become 'xxx180220'
password_to_set="xxx"+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d")

#I'd like to run this PS command to change my generated password to value stored in password_to_set variable. How do I do it?
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass ([adsi]'WinNT://valueaddco/wadmin,user').ChangePassword('/#\n\9{S;-l2H~','xxx180220')
```

Comment: On the Python side, pass your command to `subprocess.Popen` as a raw string, with the default `shell=False` setting. powershell.exe will get exactly the command you pass it.

Comment: @eryksun what if there will be a quotation in generated_password value?How do I put generated_password and password_to_set values into row string?

Answer (score 0):

I've created new1.ps file:

```
echo "changing password from $($args[0]) to $($args[1])"
([adsi]'WinNT://valueaddco/wadmingolyaa1,user').ChangePassword($($args[0]), $($args[1]))
```

It could be launched with Python code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-File', 'new.ps1', generated_password, password_to_set]
proc= Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line != b'':
        print(line.strip())
    else:
        break
```